# Blender: How to merge two faces?

Tags: models, 3d-meshes, blender

### Initial Situation

Using Blender 2.6, I often come to the same problematic setting: There are two faces on one straight line.

[image: screenshot]

### My Aim

I want to keep just one of the two selected faces, which you can see above. And all of the vertices adjoining the one face should be merged [`Alt + M` in Vertex Select Mode] with the apt vertex adjoining the other face.

[image: screenshot]

### Summary

I just simply need a tool working like Vertex Merging [`Alt + M` in Vertex Select Mode] for faces.

How can I do that easily?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. - I'm sorry, but in this Stack Exchange board I don't have enough reputation to embed images.

Answer (score 2):

Vertex merging is for vertices only, hence the name. You can do what you want by selecting each of the 4 sets of vertices separately and merging them with their appropriate counterpart one pair at time. Alternatively, you can select the lower face and move it to overlap the second, then delete the second.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. - On my screenshots, the second face hasn't got any neighbor faces - the second face is solo. I wanted to stay simple with my example screenshots. But often I need to merge two faces where both of them have neighbor faces. And then your second plan wouldn't really work for me.

Comment: `merging them` *[...]* `one pair at time` - That's a good solution and I did it that way till now. But that's just boring if you have to do it many times.

Comment: But Blender is optimized for rapid modelling, so I think there should/has to be anything tool solving my problems.

Comment: The process I described are the tools needed. Does it not solve your problem? It would be impractical to create a tool for every situation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in tool because this isn't a commonly occurring situation for most people. In particular, how did you get 3 faces, two of them connected directly aligned along a shared normal axis? To even get into this situation, it might be easier to extrude one face to get the other, and if you have an extra loop you can delete the edge loop easily. Or alternatively, you could be using the "bridge/loft" tool to connect pre-existing faces.

Comment: `bridge/loft` sounds cool. I'll try that out as soon as I can, thanks.